# Git and merging commits

Tags: git

I have several commits, some related to similar tasks, for instance:

```
eedf6b3 Task A (Continue)
12364e5 Task D
da77ed3 Task C
9e1991a Taks B (Continue)
cb345c1 Task A (Continue)
83b1c27 Task B
9b3c83c Task A
```

I would like to merge similar tasks into a single task with a new comment.
I came across 'git rebase -i ' but for some reason it didnt (or I misunderstood it....) do the trick.

Comment: @zerkms all of the commits are on my branch, how does cp helps?

Comment: you extract them into a new place, squash (using rebase) and then do whatever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git rebase` is a very powerful tool, so be careful while using it. **It is generally not a good idea to `rebase` shared commits (i.e. ones that you've pushed to GitHub, or shared with collaborators in some other way).**

Here is how you can use `rebase -i` to re-arrange your commits, assuming they go from oldest at the bottom to newest at the top:

1. `git rebase -i HEAD~7`

   This will dump you into your default text editor with a buffer containgint something like this:

   ```
   pick 9b3c83c Task A
   pick 83b1c27 Task B
   pick cb345c1 Task A (Continue)
   pick 9e1991a Taks B (Continue)
   pick da77ed3 Task C
   pick 12364e5 Task D
   pick eedf6b3 Task A (Continue)
   ```
2. First, modify the buffer so that the commits are in the *order* you want. That is, cut and paste until you get something like:

   ```
   pick 9b3c83c Task A
   pick cb345c1 Task A (Continue)
   pick eedf6b3 Task A (Continue)
   pick 83b1c27 Task B
   pick 9e1991a Taks B (Continue)
   pick da77ed3 Task C
   pick 12364e5 Task D
   ```
3. Now, change commits that are part of a previous commit from `pick` to `squash`:

   ```
   pick 9b3c83c Task A
   squash cb345c1 Task A (Continue)
   squash eedf6b3 Task A (Continue)
   pick 83b1c27 Task B
   squash 9e1991a Taks B (Continue)
   pick da77ed3 Task C
   pick 12364e5 Task D
   ```
4. Once you're happy with what you've got, save the file and exit your editor. Git will look at the file you saved and reorder the commits as you did, squashing the ones marked `squash` into the previous commit.

   This can cause conflicts, but if the different tasks were well separated they shouldn't be terribly complex ones. Just resolve those conflicts as normal. Git will prompt you with how to do this if it comes up.

The [Changing Multiple Commit Messages section of Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages) is a useful reference.

Answer (score 0):

First, to get the terminology clear:

You can't merge commits, you can only merge branches.

If you have a branch called dev and you want to have some (not all) commits in your master branch, you will have to use cherry-picking.
That means, you take some commits from the dev-branch to your master-branch.

For that check out master then use

```
git cherry-pick <commit>
```

For further reading, see the [manpage of git cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)